# The question I posted was closed without a solution

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

My question, which I posted, was closed with the given reason:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
>   checklist" – Thihara, halex, devnull, Michael0x2a, rcs

I had posted the code that I have tried and I had also mentioned the error that I got in Eclipse.

May I please know why the question was not taken up?

Comment: You posted part of [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19355648/814064) as an answer.

Comment: I fixed what @dcaswell is mentioning, but I still don't think this is a question worth reopening. You're not even saying what error you are getting.

Comment: Something tells me that "Your Answer" should be renamed to "Your Solution" on Stack Overflow, since clearly people aren't understanding what an "answer" is. (And while we're at it, change "Your Question" to "Your Problem".)

Answer (score 12):

> I had posted the code that I have tried and also I had mentioned the error that i got in eclipse.

Looking at your question it looks like this:

> Using Apache POI, how can I extract words from an MS word document based on the text color?

Neither you have posted a code nor you have posted what error you are getting. It seems you have posted your code as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374065/1369235) that is not a correct way to post your code. If you are getting error on your code, you should post it on your question. You can simply [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19355648/edit) and post code and error there. Also post only code exactly where you are getting an error. After your edit your question will go to the [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) where reviewer may open your question.